looking for help with a difficult similar triangle problem
I am trying to calculate h given the known lengths in the large equilateral triangle.

From what I remember, the relationship $\frac{x}{h} = \frac{h}{\phi-x}$ only works when all three triangles are right triangles, and the blue triangle is not a right triangle.  The next approach was to set up the similar triangles $\triangle$BA$_3$P$_1$ and $\triangle$BNB$_1$ (where A$_3$ is the point where h intersects $\overline{\text{BC}}$), but I need to know the length of x.  Does anyone know how to solve for x?

My answer below expands on my overview I gave to you earlier in this comment & the next one after it. I hope I've got all of the algebra correct now, as I checked several times & found at least one error each time up until the last time. I'll recheck again sometime to confirm. It would've been been faster & simpler to just use a fairly accurate approximation for $\phi$ instead, but I wanted to give you an exact expression, & also was somewhat curious how relatively simple it would be.

@OP For a more "automated" solution, one may try using Mass-point-geometry method as it works very well for projective-affine geometry problems.

Note I've added some more manipulations to my final algebraic expression, i.e., took out a common factor of $4$ in the denominator, and then rationalized the denominator, to get to my final relatively simple form of $\frac{\sqrt{3},(\sqrt{5} + 1)}{4\sqrt{5}}$. Since this has the same numeric value as my previous final expression, I don't think I made any mistakes there. Also, note I've checked all of my previous calculations once again, but didn't find any errors. Nonetheless, I suggest you check them yourself, if you haven't yet done so, and please let me know if you find anything wrong.

Since $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral, then $\measuredangle B_{1}CN = 60^{\circ}$. Thus, $\triangle B_1CN$ is a $30^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-90^{\circ}$ triangle, with the hypotenuse having length $\phi$, so we then have
$$\lvert NC \rvert = \frac{\phi}{2} \;\;\to\;\; \lvert BN \rvert = \frac{3\phi}{2} + 1, \;\; \lvert NB_1 \rvert = \frac{\sqrt{3}\phi}{2} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
With $\triangle BA_{3}P_{1} \sim \triangle BNB_{1}$, we get
$$\frac{\lvert BA_{3} \rvert}{\lvert A_{3}P_{1} \rvert} = \frac{\lvert BN \rvert}{\lvert NB_{1} \rvert} \;\;\to\;\; \frac{x}{h} = \frac{\frac{3\phi}{2} + 1}{\frac{\sqrt{3}\phi}{2}} = \frac{3\phi + 2}{\sqrt{3}\phi} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
From $C_1$, draw the line perpendicular to $BC$ up to cross $BC$ at $N_1$. With $\measuredangle C_{1}BN_{1} = 60^{\circ}$, then $\triangle C_{1}BN_{1}$ is a $30^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-90^{\circ}$ triangle, with the hypotenuse having length $\phi + 1$, so then
$$\lvert BN_1 \rvert = \frac{\phi + 1}{2} \;\;\to\;\; \lvert N_{1}A_{1} \rvert = \phi - \frac{\phi + 1}{2} = \frac{\phi - 1}{2}, \;\; \lvert N_{1}C_{1} \rvert = \frac{\sqrt{3}(\phi + 1)}{2} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
Since $\triangle A_{1}A_{3}P_{1} \sim \triangle A_{1}N_{1}C_{1}$, we have
$$\frac{\lvert A_{3}A_{1} \rvert}{\lvert A_{3}P_{1} \rvert} = \frac{\lvert N_{1}A_{1} \rvert}{\lvert N_{1}C_{1} \rvert} \;\;\to\;\; \frac{\phi - x}{h} = \frac{\frac{\phi - 1}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}(\phi + 1)}{2}} = \frac{\phi - 1}{\sqrt{3}(\phi + 1)} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
Next, the right side of \eqref{eq2A} divided by the right side of \eqref{eq4A} gives, using the special relationship of $\phi^2 = \phi + 1$ of the Golden ratio, that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\frac{x}{h}}{\frac{\phi - x}{h}} & = \frac{\frac{3\phi + 2}{\sqrt{3}\phi}}{\frac{\phi - 1}{\sqrt{3}(\phi + 1)}} \\
\frac{x}{\phi - x} & = \frac{(3\phi + 2)(\phi + 1)}{\phi(\phi - 1)} \\
\frac{x}{\phi - x} & = \frac{(3\phi + 2)\phi^2}{\phi(\phi - 1)} \\
\frac{x}{\phi - x} & = \frac{3\phi^2 + 2\phi}{\phi - 1} \\
\frac{x}{\phi - x} & = \frac{5\phi + 3}{\phi - 1} \\
x(\phi - 1) & = (\phi - x)(5\phi + 3) \\
x(\phi - 1) & = 5\phi^2 + 3\phi - x(5\phi + 3) \\
x(6\phi + 2) & = 8\phi + 5 \\
x & = \frac{8\phi + 5}{6\phi + 2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$
Using this in \eqref{eq2A}, along with $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$, then gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
h & = \frac{\sqrt{3}\phi x}{3\phi + 2} \\
& = \frac{\sqrt{3}(8\phi^2 + 5\phi)}{(6\phi + 2)(3\phi + 2)} \\
& = \frac{\sqrt{3}(8(\phi + 1) + 5\phi)}{18\phi^2 + 18\phi + 4} \\
& = \frac{\sqrt{3}(13\phi + 8)}{36\phi + 22} \\
& = \sqrt{3}\left(\frac{13\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right) + 8}{36\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right) + 22}\right) \\
& = \sqrt{3}\left(\frac{13\sqrt{5} + 29}{36\sqrt{5} + 80}\right) \\
& = \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\left(\frac{(13\sqrt{5} + 29)(9\sqrt{5} - 20)}{(9\sqrt{5} + 20)(9\sqrt{5} - 20)}\right) \\
& = \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\left(\frac{5 + \sqrt{5}}{5}\right) \\
& = \frac{\sqrt{3}\,(\sqrt{5} + 1)}{4\sqrt{5}} \\
& \approx 0.62666
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$
Note that using $\sqrt{5} + 1 = 2\phi$ and $\sqrt{5} = 2\phi - 1$, we can use the second last line above to get $h = \frac{\sqrt{3}\,\phi}{2(2\phi - 1)}$ instead.

An alternative approach (though not widely accepted). I'm gonna use Mass-point method. Here I use $[ABC]$ to denote area of triangle ABC. First, we label masses at points so that they "balance":
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textrm{Point}&    C&      A&    B_a&  B_c& B& B_1\\ \hline
m(\textrm{Point})& 1+\phi& \phi&  \frac{\phi^2}{1+\phi}& \frac{(1+\phi)^2} {\phi}& \frac{\phi^2}{1+\phi}+\frac{(1+\phi)^2}{\phi}&  1+2\phi  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
We have:
$$h=\frac{2}{BA_1}[A_1 P_1 B]=\frac{2}{BA_1}\frac{BP_1}{BB_1}\frac{BA_1}{BC}[BB_1 C]=\frac{2}{BA_1}\frac{BP_1}{BB_1}\frac{BA_1}{BC}\frac{CB_1}{CA}[ABC]\tag{1}$$
$$=\frac{2}{\phi}\frac{m(B_1)}{m(B_1)+m(B)} \frac{\phi}{1+2\phi} \frac{\phi}{1+2\phi}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}AB^2\tag{2}$$
$$=\frac{2}{\phi}\frac{1+2\phi}{\frac{\phi^2}{1+\phi}+\frac{(1+\phi)^2}{\phi}+1+2\phi}\frac{\phi}{1+2\phi} \frac{\phi}{1+2\phi}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}(1+2\phi)^2=0.62666\ldots \tag{3}$$
Explanation:

$(1)$: I used the fact $[XYZ]=\frac{1}{2}(XY)(XZ)\sin(XY,XZ)=\frac{1}{2}(YZ)(XH)$, this is why the product of ratio appears (the fact that some triangles share the same angle).
$(2)$: $[ABC]=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}[AB]^2$ because triangle ABC is equilateral. $\frac{BP_1}{BB_1}=\frac{m(B_1)}{m(B_1)+m(B)}$ is a simple fact from the method itself.
The table:
-We need to find couple of values of $m(A)$ and $m(C)$ so that $m(C)
(CB_1)=m(A)(AB_1)$. $m(B_1)=m(A)+m(C)$ follows.
-Similarly these constrains must be satisfied:
$m(B_a)(B C_1)=m(A)(AC_1); m(B_c)(B A_1)=m(C)(CA_1)$. $m(B)=m(B_a)+m(B_c)$ follows.

